# Adding text with an action in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, actions

I make multi option proofs on a daily basis and have started setting up actions to simplify my repetitive steps. Is there a way to add text that is consistent on every proof by using an action? I have tried using the "insert menu item" option but when I type *text* in the box and hit search, only *texture* comes up. I also searched for *type*, and that added the word type to my action, but didn't let me add the actual text. I am also trying to add "resize artboard" to an action but am having no luck.
On the image below you can see the "Option A, Option B and Option C". When I have a proof with 3 plates like this, I would like to automate adding the "OPTION" text since it is in the same place every time.[image]

Comment: Hi Welcome to GDSE. Not sure if this is any help for your specific use case, but you can use data merge in Illustrator. Here's [Adobe's help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/data-driven-graphics-templates-variables.html) on the subject.

Comment: Unfortunately Data Merge will not help me with this dilemma. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Scripting time!

Comment: I haven't learned that yet. I was hoping there was a way to do it with actions.